# IOS Add a View (UIButton or UILable) below UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have been doing an Project for IOS which is written in Objective C. Theres a requirement where i have to put a Button or Label below a table view which kind of act as an Dialog like view over an WebView. There is already an header view embedded into the table view, its work well, but when i try to place the button or label below the table view using Storyboard its not working as expected it actually not positioning below the TableView. Below is the image how my View is laid out :

[image]

This is how it looks currently :

[image]

Below is the code for my view controller :

ViewController.h:

```
#import "FlatUIKit.h"

@interface NothiViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet    UIWebView           *mainWebView;
    IBOutlet    UISegmentedControl  *segmentControl;

    IBOutlet    UIView      *viewNothiPermittedUsers;
    IBOutlet    UILabel     *labelTitleNothiPermittedUsers;
    IBOutlet    UITableView *tableViewNothiPermittedUsers;
}

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray    *arrNothiPermittedUsers;
@property(nonatomic,retain) ModelNothi  *currentModelNothi;

- (void)updateRightBar:(BOOL)all;

@end

@interface CellNothiPermittedUserList : UITableViewCell
{
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet  UILabel    *labelUserName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet  FUIButton   *buttonSend;

@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
    @interface NothiViewController ()<UIWebViewDelegate,CustomAlertViewDelegate>
{
    RequestNothiActionApiType currentNothiActionApiType;
    AlertType                 currentAlertType;
}
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSData *dataNotangsho;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSData *dataPotrangsho;
@end

@implementation NothiViewController
@synthesize currentModelNothi;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.view.backgroundColor = APP_VIEW_BACKGROUND_COLOR;
    mainWebView.delegate = self;
    mainWebView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
    mainWebView.opaque = YES;
    mainWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;

    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f];
    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font
                                                           forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
    [segmentControl setTitleTextAttributes:attributes
                                  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    segmentControl.tintColor = COLOR_LOGIN_BUTTON;

    self.dataNotangsho  = nil;
    self.dataPotrangsho = nil;

    currentNothiActionApiType = API_TYPE_NOTANGSHO;
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"data_ref": @"api",
                             @"api_key": API_KEY,
                             @"user_designation": [AppSupporter sharedInstance].currentDesignationID};
    NSString *api = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",API_NOTHI_NOTANGSHO,self.currentModelNothi.nothiParts];

    CGRect frame = segmentControl.frame;
    frame.origin.y = NAV_BAR_HEIGHT + STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT;
    segmentControl.frame = frame;
    segmentControl.backgroundColor = APP_VIEW_BACKGROUND_COLOR;

    // Delay execution of my block for 10 seconds.
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, .5 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self connectServer:api withParams:params withProgressMessage:@"তথ‍্য লোড হচ্ছে, একটু অপেক্ষা করুন..."];
    });

    viewNothiPermittedUsers.hidden = YES;

    viewNothiPermittedUsers.backgroundColor      = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0F alpha:0.7f];

    labelTitleNothiPermittedUsers.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [labelTitleNothiPermittedUsers.layer setCornerRadius:8.0f];
    labelTitleNothiPermittedUsers.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    labelTitleNothiPermittedUsers.font = [UIFont boldFlatFontOfSize:16.0f];

    tableViewNothiPermittedUsers.backgroundColor   = [UIColor whiteColor];
    tableViewNothiPermittedUsers.tableFooterView   = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame : CGRectZero];
    [tableViewNothiPermittedUsers.layer setCornerRadius:8.0f];
    tableViewNothiPermittedUsers.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(notifyNothiForward:) name:EventNothiForward object:nil];
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Note i am kind of new to IOS programming and the project was written by someone else, which i just got now to extend it, so i am little aware of positioning views at the moment.

Comment: can u try footer view for table ?

Comment: Footer scroll with the tables, which is not what i want. The view need to stick below the Table View.

Comment: you are missing the constraints !

Comment: Contrains on footer view of table not to be scroll along?